# how to write .htaccess for subdirectory files?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

May be this question will be duplicate.
I am a newbie php programmer.
What is the basic .htaccess file for a website having subdirectories?

For Ex:
My website's index page can be easily opened.But when i am trying to open www.example.com/subdirectory/post1.php it will show me www.example.com/index.php.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: seems like a redirect is defined somewhere. could you share the content of current .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

You can put a .httaccess file in your subdirectory to turn off the mode rewrite for that folder. In the file you need to put the following line:

RewriteEngine Off

Or you can rewrite the main .htaccess file to skip that folder.